# How works sprite. spritecollide?

Tags: python, pygame

Want to create a group with 10 images. The images should later on the screen not overlap. I try to check that with sprite.spritecollide. somewhere / somehow images disappear. probably using Spritecollide incorrectly.

```
ii = -1
while ii < 10:
      ii+=1   
      img = pygame.image.load(f"Bilder/Gegenstaende/geg{ii}.png")    
      img = pygame.transform.scale(img,(100,100))  
      m = Landschaft(img) 
      zzz = 0          
      hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(m,land,True)        
      if len(hits) >=1:
        for hit_sprite in hits:
            zzz +=1 
            ii = ii -zzz          
      else: 
        land.add(m)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) has a *doKill* argument. If the parameter is `True`, all [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) objects that collide will be removed from the [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group).

You have to pass `False` to *doKill*:

<s>`hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(m,land,True)`</s>

```py
hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(m, land, False)
```

---

Note that if there is no space on the screen, you will get an infinite loop. Use the application loop to add the images one at a time:

```
desired_number = 10

while run:

    if len(land) < desired_number:

        ii = len(land)   
        img = pygame.image.load(f"Bilder/Gegenstaende/geg{ii}.png")    
        img = pygame.transform.scale(img,(100,100))  
        m = Landschaft(img) 
      
        if not pygame.sprite.spritecollide(m, land, False):
            land.add(m)

    # [...]
```